# Prove that $\frac{6+\cos (n^2)}{n}\to0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Prove that the sequence $\left(\frac{6+\cos (n^2)}{n}\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}^*}$ approaches $0$. Prove directly from the definition of convergence. (Don't use the squeezing theorem.)

First of all, I had to determine by myself that it approaches $0$, so if I am incorrect about that, please let me know. Here is my formal proof thus far, which I might or might not be choosing N correctly.

Proof: Let $\varepsilon >0$. Take N = $\frac{7}{\varepsilon}.$ Since $\frac{7}{n}$ > $\left(\frac{6+\cos (n^2)}{n}\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}^*}$

Let $n$ be a natural number. Then for $n \geq N$, we have $\left|\left(\frac{6+\cos (n^2)}{n}\right)- 0\right|$ < $\left|\frac{7}{n}\right| < \left|\frac{7}{N}\right|= \varepsilon$.

This completes the proof.

Comment: Reposting since I think I did it incorrectly the first time and formatted poorly.

Comment: I downvoted it because you reposted the same problem. You should edit the original if there is a problem, not repost the same problem.

Comment: Ok will do that next time. Figured no one would look at that post anymore. Sorry.

Comment: You could also delete the original question.

Comment: It won't let me since there are answers, it says.

Comment: Ah, right. Well I'll undo my down vote then, since you now know you've been naughty.

Comment: Oops, it won't let me undo it.

Comment: That's alright. Do you know if my proof looks correct?

Comment: @RemyM: If you edit your post, it will be put back at the top of the active list, just as if you had freshly posted it. As this is the default way questions are presented, it means that people are about as likely to notice an edit as they are to notice a new post.

Answer (score 3):

Note that sequence $\left\vert\frac{6+\cos (n^2)}{n}\right\vert\le \left\vert\frac{6+1}{n}\right\vert<\varepsilon$ from here $N=\frac{7}{\varepsilon}$

Comment: You're saying I should include this in my proof?

Comment: Perhaps I would even use the triangle inequality as $|6+\cos(n^2)| \leqslant 6 + |\cos(n^2)| \leqslant 6 + 1 = 7$.